# How to set max date and default date in Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Am using this [Boostrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), I want to set max date as 1 year from start date, after 1 year the dates should be disabled and once the start date is been selected, the end date should automatically set to 3 months from the selected date but it should be disabled only after 1 year from the start date minimum dates can be even 2 days.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="startDate">Start Date<span>*</span>(MM/DD/YYYY)</label> 
    <input class="step__field form-control hasPlaceholder date-input" id="startDate" name="startDate" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="endDate">End Date(MM/DD/YYYY)</label>
    <input class="form-control hasPlaceholder date-input step__field" id="endDate" name="endDate" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

JS

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
$('#startDate').datepicker({
    startDate: today
});
```

If you can suggest me any other plugin, Please do and create a JS fiddle with the requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear()-1, nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $('#startDate').datepicker('startDate', today);

    $('#startDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        var today1 = new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(), ev.date.getMonth()+3, ev.date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        $('#endDate').datepicker('setStartDate',today1);
    });
```

**Edit:**

```
$('#startDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var set_Date = new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(), ev.date.getMonth()+3, ev.date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var start_date = new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(), ev.date.getMonth(), ev.date.getDate()+2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var end_date = new Date(ev.date.getFullYear()+1, ev.date.getMonth(), ev.date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $('#endDate').datepicker('setStartDate',start_date);
    $('#endDate').datepicker('setDate',set_Date);
    $('#endDate').datepicker('setEndDate',end_date);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, Am sorry I dint explain well, The max range of the end date should be 1 year from start date minimum range can be even 2 days but it should be disabled after 1 year and once the start date is been selected the end date should populate itself by 3 months from start date

Comment: How disable dates for a year after from the start date?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally accomplished what I was looking for with the code of @Parth Patel, Thank you  so much, for those who're looking for the same requirement, this is the code

```
var nowDate = new Date();
  var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(),
      0, 0, 0, 0);
  $('#startDate').datepicker({
      startDate: today
  });
  $('#startDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      var selectedStartDate = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
      var year1 = new Date(selectedStartDate.getFullYear() + 1,
          selectedStartDate.getMonth(), selectedStartDate.getDate(),
          0, 0, 0, 0);
      var today1 = new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(), ev.date.getMonth() +
          3, ev.date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      $('#endDate').datepicker('setStartDate', today);
      $('#endDate').datepicker('update', today1);
      $('#endDate').datepicker('setEndDate', year1);
  });
```